# S3 pricing with aws Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Do I get charged for transfer from S3 to aws Lambda?

For example a user uploads a file client side to my S3 bucket. My aws lambda retrieves the file to generate thumbnails. Does that count as S3 out to internet or S3 to cloudfront or something else?

Lambda and S3 are in the same region.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There is **no Data Transfer charge between an AWS Lambda function and Amazon S3** in the same region.

From [AWS Lambda – Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/):

> Data transferred between Amazon S3 ... and AWS Lambda functions in the same AWS Region is free.

However, if your Lambda function is **configured to use a VPC**, there will be a small (1c/GB) charge for traffic exiting the VPC. This traffic would be routed through a NAT Gateway, which has a public IP address.

From [EC2 Instance Pricing – Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/):

> IPv4: Data transferred “in” to and “out” from public or Elastic IPv4 address is charged at $0.01/GB in each direction.

This charge does NOT apply if the Lambda function connects to the Internet directly (by NOT connecting to a VPC).

Comment: No data transfer charge, but there still would be some "per request" charge. Correct?

Comment: I did not address request charges, since your question only asked about Data Transfer. Any such request charges would be the normal charges incurred for use of Amazon S3 regardless of how, or from where, it is accessed. See: [Amazon S3 Simple Storage Service Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

Answer (score 1):

If Lambda reads/writes data from S3 you will be billed for requests and data stored.

for example:
PUT, COPY, POST, LIST requests (per 1,000 requests) - $0.005

GET, SELECT, and all other requests (per 1,000 requests) - $0.0004

Prices in different regions change slightly.

Answer (score 0):

NO.

"Data transferred from an Amazon S3 bucket to any AWS service(s) within the same AWS Region as the S3 bucket (including to a different account in the same AWS Region)."

Please refer to the attached link below at the Data Transfer tab

[Amazon S3 pricing - Data Transfer](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)